# Extracting XML elements which contains a certain string with sed

Tags: bash, xml-parsing, sed, awk

I have a file like below

```
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="show databases"/>
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-29T17:27:53" NAME="Quit" CONNECTION_ID="12" STATUS="0"/>
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="show grants for root@localhost"/>
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="create table stamp like paper"/>
```

Here each record begin with `<AUDIT_RECORD` and end with `"/>` and the record might spread across multiple lines.

My requirement is to display result like below

```
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="show databases"/>
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="show grants for root@localhost"/>
  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="create table stamp like paper"/>
```

for that purpose I have used

```
sed -n "/Query/,/\/>/p" file.txt
```

but it is displaying the entire file including the record with the string "Quit".

Can anyone help me regarding this? Also please let me know if it is possible to match exactly string named "Query" ( like `grep -w "Query"` ).

Comment: So you want to skip the line containing "Quit"?

Comment: I want to display only records with Query and record may spread across multiple lines. Here it is sample file there are many strings like Query,Quit, etc but i want only records which has the string Query.

Comment: time to consider to use an xml parser

Comment: I have to achieve this only with sed or any shell commands because its a statement part of a shell script

Comment: @vidyadhar xml parser doesn't conflict with shell script. what I meant is, sed is not the right tool to do it, particularly you mentioned, it could be crossing multiple lines.

Comment: `sed` works with lines, so it is going to take a good bit more work to make it treat records that span multiple lines as a single entity.

Comment: `sed` is an external program. If you system has a XML parser available, then calling it is the equivalent to calling `sed`, or `awk` or `perl`. Your sample data doesn't really reflect the condition that your "records" are spread over multiple lines. Your code might work if the records really where on multiple lines, but as is `/query/,/\//` is a range expression meant to match multiple lines and (as you see) will not match a single line of input. Good luck!

Comment: So, you HAVE to use sed?

Comment: Actually, I copy pasted your input (split each record across 2 lines though) and your sed command, and... it seems to work. I mean, I don't get the record with "Quit" in it.

Comment: If you need to cross lines, do NOT use sed use awk instead. Also parsing input records that can span lines is a very different problem from records that are always on a single line so update your posted sample input/output to show representative multi-line cases.

Comment: your sed command seems to have an extra slash after query, before comma... sed -n "/Query/,/\/>/p" file.txt ... try sed -n '/Query,/\/>/p' file.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @choroba that an XML parser is the right tool. However, if there isn't one available you could try this awk script:

```
awk '/Query/{print RS" "$0}' RS='<AUDIT_RECORD' file
```

Comment: @vidyadhar because you have to set the record separator (with the `RS=` option) in order to handle records that span multiple lines

Comment: Thanks but this is not working while using with user defined variables (awk '/"'$line'"/{print RS" "$0}' RS='<AUDIT_RECORD' file)

Comment: @vidyadhar Thy this: `awk -v line="$line" '$0 ~ line{print RS" "$0}' RS='<AUDIT_RECORD' file`, i.e to pass the variable using the `-v` option

Comment: Note that this is gawk-only, is using the start of the next record instead of the end of the current record as the separator, and will produce a, probably undesirable, newline at the end of the output. Might be fine, just worth mentioning IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk so you can set the RS to more than one character:

```
$ cat file
<AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query"
                CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="show databases"/>
<AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-29T17:27:53"
        NAME="Quit" CONNECTION_ID="12" STATUS="0"/>
<AUDIT_RECORD
        TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10"
     STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="show grants for root@localhost"/>
<AUDIT_RECORD
        TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29"
        NAME="Query"
        CONNECTION_ID="10"
        STATUS="0"
        SQLTEXT="create table stamp like paper"/>
$
$ gawk -v RS='\\/>\n' -v ORS= '/Query/{print $0 RT}' file
<AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query"
                CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="show databases"/>
<AUDIT_RECORD
        TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10"
     STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="show grants for root@localhost"/>
<AUDIT_RECORD
        TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29"
        NAME="Query"
        CONNECTION_ID="10"
        STATUS="0"
        SQLTEXT="create table stamp like paper"/>
$
$ gawk -v RS='\\/>\n' -v ORS= '/Query/{$1=$1; print $0 RT}' file
<AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="show databases"/>
<AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="show grants for root@localhost"/>
<AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-07-30T17:52:29" NAME="Query" CONNECTION_ID="10" STATUS="0" SQLTEXT="create table stamp like paper"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The input is probably XML. Use a proper parser to handle it, especially if the records span over multiple lines. For example, [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open file.xml ;
remove //AUDIT_RECORD[not(@NAME="Query")] ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: cant i achieve this through sed

Comment: @vidyadhar: For the general case, no. If the input is not *any well-formed XML*, but a specific subset, it might be possible.

Answer (score 2):

My proposed sed solution :

```
sed 's/<[^>]*\"Quit\"[^>]*>//' file.txt
```

For records spanning multiple lines, try :

```
sed '{:q;N;s/\n/ /g;t q}' file.txt | sed 's/<[^>]*\"Quit\"[^>]*>//'
```

Add line feed RS :

```
... | sed 's|/>|/>\n|g'
```

Comment: its working but is there any way to match exactly the string Quit

Comment: Do you mean matching "Quit" including the quotes? `\"Quit\"`

Comment: Edited the answer above for the quotes.

Comment: i am using sed 's/<[^\>]*$line[^\>]*\>//' file.txt where line=`echo "\"Quit"\"`   Here it is matching "Quits" "Quiting" strings as well

Comment: Try 's/<[^>]*\"'$line'\"[^>]*>//'
where line=Quit (note: I removed a lot of backslashes in later edits)